# Is it possible to Call object methods using html tag inline event attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to understand the concepts of core javascript.
As we all know, We can call functions which are in global context for some event like this.

## Html

```
<span class="name" onclick="clicked()">Name</span>
```

## JavaScript

```
function clicked(){
   alert("span clicked");
}
```

But why we cannot call function i.e object method like following:

## Html

```
<span class="name" onclick="nameobject.clicked()">Name</span>
```

## javaScript

```
var nameobject = {
   clicked: function(){
     alert("Clicked");
   }
}
```

Is there something I am missing? Can someone help me on this?

Comment: You can call it but your js code should bind before html

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in stacksnippet ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it but your `js` code should bind before `html code`
You can check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ta61zxkt/)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var nameobject = {
   clicked: function(){
     alert("Clicked");
   }
}
</script>
<span class="name" onclick="nameobject.clicked()">Name</span>
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, Without going through some minor error I posted my question here. We can call JS even after Html code, as object will be available globally. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no such condition exists. It would work either way.

```html
<span class="name" onclick="nameobject.click()">Name</span>
<span onclick="clicked()">Name2</span>
<script>
var nameobject = {
   click: function(){
     alert("span 1 Clicked");
   }
}
var clicked = function(){
  alert("span 2 clicked");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, Correct. As I mentioned above, without analyzing error i posted question. It would work either way.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you do NOT include your object declaration inside a $(document).ready() or window.onload function.

Example **without** window.onload:

```js
var nameObject = {
   clicked: function(){
     alert("Clicked");
   }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="nameObject.clicked()">
Click Me
</button>
```

Example **with** window.onload(throws error)

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var nameObject = {
   clicked: function(){
     alert("Clicked");
   }
  }
};
```

```html
<button onClick="nameObject.clicked()">
Click Me
</button>
```